# Python - Basic CLI Email Client

Tags: python, console, email, client

This is a basic CLI email client in Python. It can send plain text emails and view inbox. `settings.json` contains a list of SMTP and IMAP servers used for different providers. This file can be edited.

client.py

```
import argparse
import email
import getpass
import imaplib
import json
import os
import re
import smtplib
import ssl
import webbrowser


def clean(text):
    # Clean text for creating a folder.
    return "".join(c if c.isalnum() else "_" for c in text)


def get_email():
    user_email = input("Email: ")
    # Validate the email entered.
    while not re.match(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", user_email):
        print("Error: Email provided is invalid.")
        user_email = input("Email: ")
    return user_email

def get_credentials():
    user_email = get_email()
    # Mask the password entered.
    password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Password: ")
    return user_email, password


def new_email():
    email, password = get_credentials()
    smtp_server = ""
    with open("settings.json", "r") as settings_file:
        settings = json.load(settings_file)
        try:
            smtp_server = settings[email[email.find("@") + 1 : email.rfind(".")]]["smtp_server"]
        except KeyError:
            print("Error: Email provider not supported.")
            return
    recipient = get_email()
    subject = input("Subject: ")
    content = input("Message: ")
    message = "Subject:" + subject + "\n\n" + content
    # Set up SMTP server.
    port = 587 
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    # Try to log in and send the email.
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(email, password)
        server.sendmail(email, recipient, message)
    except Exception as e:
        # Print any error messages to stdout.
        print(e)
    finally:
        server.quit()


def view_inbox():
    # Repeat prompting for credentials until correct ones are provided.
    logged_in = False
    while not logged_in:
        user_email, password = get_credentials()

        # Try to load the IMAP server name from settings.json file.
        imap_server_name = ""
        with open("settings.json", "r") as settings_file:
            settings = json.load(settings_file)
            try:
                imap_server_name = settings[user_email[user_email.find("@") + 1 : user_email.rfind(".")]]["imap_server"]
            except KeyError:
                print("Error: Email provider not supported.")
                continue
        
        # Initialise the IMAP server.
        imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server_name)
        try:
            imap_server.login(user_email, password)
        except:
            print("Error: Incorrect credentials.")
        else:
            logged_in = True

    status, messages = imap_server.select("INBOX")
    while True:
        try:
            emails_to_load = int(input("Select a number of emails to load: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Invalid value.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    messages = int(messages[0])
    for i in range(messages, messages - emails_to_load, -1):
        data = imap_server.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)" )
        for response_part in data:
            arr = response_part[0]
            if isinstance(arr, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(str(arr[1],"utf-8"))
                email_subject = msg["subject"] if msg["subject"] else ""
                email_from = msg["from"]
                print("From : " + email_from + "\n")
                print("Subject : " + email_subject + "\n")
                # If the message is multipart.
                if msg.is_multipart():
                    # Iterate over email parts.
                    for part in msg.walk():
                        # Extract content type of the email.
                        content_type = part.get_content_type()
                        content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                        try:
                            # Get the email body.
                            body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                        except:
                            pass
                        if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                            # Print text/plain emails and skip attachments.
                            print(body)
                        elif "attachment" in content_disposition:
                            # Download attachment.
                            filename = part.get_filename()
                            if filename:
                                folder_name = clean(email_subject)
                                if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                                    # Make a folder for this email (named after the subject).
                                    os.mkdir(folder_name)
                                filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                                # Download attachment and save it.
                                open(filepath, "wb").write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                else:
                    # Extract content type of email.
                    content_type = msg.get_content_type()
                    # Get the email body.
                    body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                    if content_type == "text/plain":
                        # Print only text email parts.
                        print(body)
                if content_type == "text/html":
                    answer = input("The following email contains HTML. Would you like to open it (y/n)?: ")
                    while answer != "y" and answer != "n":
                        print("Error: Invalid answer.")
                        answer = input("The following email contains HTML. Would you like to download and open it (y/n)?: ")
                    if answer == "y":
                        # If it is HTML, create a new HTML file and open it in browser if the user wishes to do so.
                        folder_name = clean(email_subject)
                        if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                            # Make a folder for this email (named after the subject).
                            os.mkdir(folder_name)
                        filename = "index.html"
                        filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                        # Write the file.
                        open(filepath, "w").write(body)
                        # Open in the default browser.
                        webbrowser.open(filepath)
                print("=" * 100)

    imap_server.close()
    imap_server.logout()


def add_server():
    # Add a server to the settings.
    type = input("Type of server (SMTP / IMAP): ")
    while type.casefold() != "smtp" and type.casefold() != "imap":
        print("Error: Type must be SMTP or IMAP.")
        type = input("Type of server (SMTP / IMAP): ")

    with open("settings.json", "r+") as settings_file:
        name = input("Email provider: ")
        settings = json.load(settings_file) 
        if name in settings and type.casefold() + "_server" in settings[name]:
            print("Error: This provider already exists. You can try editing it.")
        else:
            server = input("Email server: ")
            if name in settings:
                settings[name][type.casefold() + "_server"] = server
                settings_file.seek(0)
                json.dump(settings, settings_file, indent=4)
            else:
                settings[name] = {
                    type.casefold() + "_server": server
                }
                settings_file.seek(0)
                json.dump(settings, settings_file, indent=4)


def edit_server():
    # Edit server in the settings.
    type = input("Type of server (SMTP / IMAP): ")
    while type.casefold() != "smtp" and type.casefold() != "imap":
        print("Error: Type must be SMTP or IMAP.")
        type = input("Type of server (SMTP / IMAP): ")

    with open("settings.json", "r+") as settings_file:
        name = input("Email provider: ")
        while not name:
            print("Error: Email provider can\'t be empty.")
            name = input("Email provider: ")
        settings = json.load(settings_file)
        if name not in settings or type.casefold() + "_server" not in settings[name]:
            print("Error: This provider doesn\'t exist. You can try adding it.")
        else:
            server = input("Email server: ")
            while not server:
                print("Error: Email server can\'t be empty. You can try removing it.")
                server = input("Email server: ")
            settings[name][type.casefold() + "_server"] = server
            settings_file.seek(0)
            json.dump(settings, settings_file, indent=4)


def remove_server():
    with open("settings.json", "r") as settings_file:
        name = input("Email provider: ")
        while not name:
            print("Error: Email provider can\'t be empty.")
            name = input("Email provider: ")
        settings = json.load(settings_file)
        while name not in settings:
            print("Error: This provider doesn\'t exist.")
            name = input("Email provider: ")
        else:
            answer = input("Are you sure (y/n)?: ")
            while answer != "y" and answer != "n":
                print("Error: Invalid answer.")
                answer = input("Are you sure (y/n)?: ")
            if answer == "y":
                del settings[name]
                with open("settings.json", "w") as settings_file:
                    json.dump(settings, settings_file, indent=4)


arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument("action", help="view/send/add/edit/remove")
args = arg_parser.parse_args()
# Dictionary that matches the value of action argument to a function that is supposed to be called.
try:
    action_to_function = {"view": view_inbox, "send": new_email, "add": add_server, "edit": edit_server, "remove": remove_server}
    action_to_function[args.action]()
except KeyError:
    arg_parser.print_help()
```

settings.json

```
{
    "outlook": {
        "smtp_server": "smtp.office365.com",
        "imap_server": "imap-mail.outlook.com"
    },
    "gmail": {
        "smtp_server": "smtp.gmail.com",
        "imap_server": "imap.gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Regex substitution

Your `clean` would be much simpler if you used the `re` module to substitute all non-alphanumeric characters, rather than iterating through the characters yourself, having a ternary and then having to re-join to a string.

### Email validation

This regex:

```
[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+
```

is, unfortunately, woefully insufficient in guaranteeing a valid email address. A trivial false positive is

```
'            @            .          '
```

There are [many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/how-to-check-for-valid-email-address) on how to be a little more careful, but this is a "hard problem", so your best bet is to call into a library like `py3-validate-email`, which can actually issue network calls to validate email addresses.

### File scope

```
with open("settings.json", "r") as settings_file:
    settings = json.load(settings_file)
    try:
        smtp_server = settings[email[email.find("@") + 1 : email.rfind(".")]]["smtp_server"]
    except KeyError:
        print("Error: Email provider not supported.")
        return
```

is done with the file as soon as you have `settings`, so the `try` and onward should be de-indented.

### Context management

It's good that you have a `finally` guaranteeing `server.quit`, but it would be better to put the `server` in a `with`, since `SMTP` is a context manager.

Your IMAP calls

```
imap_server.close()
imap_server.logout()
```

are missing similar protection.

### Method complexity

`view_inbox` needs to be broken up into subroutines. It's way too long and complex right now.

### Built-in shadowing

```
type = input("Type of server (SMTP / IMAP): ")
```

is a bad idea. `type` is a critical built-in that you've now made inaccessible in the rest of `add_server`.

### Escaping

```
        print("Error: Email provider can\'t be empty.")
```

doesn't need a backslash since you have double quotes.

### Main guard

From `arg_parser` onward, that needs to live in a `main()` method protected by a `__name__` guard.